# Exchange server 2013 connection with java

Tags: java, exchangewebservices, exchange-server-2013

I'm trying to connect to Exchange server 2013 using java 7. The problem is when I try to set Exchange version
`ExchangeService service = new ExchangeService(ExchangeVersion.Exchange2010_SP1);`,
 2007 & 2010 is the only options available.
Note that I'm using **exchange-ws-api-1.1.5.jar**.
Is there updated jar for exchange 2013. 
 Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Check out https://github.com/OfficeDev/ews-java-api/. That should work with 2013 no problem :).